# Security of SSH generated in GitKraken

Tags: security, ssh, gitkraken

I have a question regarding security of a SSH key generated in GitKraken. Until now, I’ve been using SSH key generated with PuTTYgen and local SSH agent (Pageant). It works well and I like the fact that I can encrypt my private key with a passphrase so, while I am not an expert in the field of security, it feels safe.

Recently, I’ve started to use GitKraken (https://www.gitkraken.com/) and it has a built in option to generate SSH keys and configure itself to use them. This is faster to use, and eliminates the need for PuTTYgen and Pageant, but it doesn't prompt me with an option to encrypt my private key.

Does this mean that anyone with an access to my computer can use my private key or it is somehow protected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this mean that anyone with an access to my computer can use my private key or it is somehow protected?

Yes, it can be used by anyone with access to the file.

[You can test this by running `ssh-keygen -yf gitkraken_rsa` on the generated private key file](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/129729). If the key was protected, it would prompt you for a password (which is not the case).